# How can I build a custom address locator?

Tags: geocoding, address, arcgis-platform

How can I geocode internal locations of, for example, an airport terminal via a custom address locator?

All I have is the footprint of the building itself.

I started by drawing out the footprints of the individual amenities within the building (which I'm able to do fine via the Editor tool). I also created an address file with store name, type, and concourse letter. Unfortunately, my building footprint does not reference any of these fields. I was hoping to geocode my "address" table onto the polygons I created.

Is there a reference to Esri lessons (for a custom address locator such as this)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What do you mean by "hoping to geocode address table onto the polygons"?  Have you tried doing a spatial join?